# Ubuntu MATE graphics problems

Tags: ubuntu-mate, caja

I have just installed Ubuntu MATE 16.04 on my t450, but I have a problem: when I boot my PC, the graphics of the desktop is very ugly. It look likes this:

[image]

[image]

It should look like this instead:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Seems that I solved the issue. I installed 
`apt-get install gnome-setting-deamon` and now all works great!

As @9a3eedi saw, this is not THE solution,for mate is `mate-setting-deamon` the package.I deleted `gnome-setting-deamon` and the pc worked in the same way.

***So I don't know the solution and why I got that problem.***

Comment: Is this really the correct solution? Ubuntu MATE does not use gnome, it uses MATE, so the correct package would be mate-settings-deamon, which is already installed in my system.

Comment: hi, I didn't say that mine is the correct solution. But installing that package I solved. This evening I'll try to remove it and  check for `mate-settings-deamon`